# When using the redim preserve statement, can you explain the difference between using it inside the Loop statement and using it outside?

Tags: excel, vba

I unconsciously used the redim preserve statement inside the loop statement. I thought it was faster and more suitable. Compared to Scott Craner's method below, I realized that my method was very wrong. Please explain the problem of the working principle when using the redim preserve statement in the loop statement.

Code test results.
There is a 71 times difference in speed.

```
Loop in:  17.77539 
Scott's Loop out:  0.25
```

Code to be compared

```
Sub set2DArrayinLoop()
    Dim arr(1 To 1000000) As String
    Dim arrNew() As String
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, j As Integer
    Dim st, et
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr) - 3 Step 5
        arr(i) = "a"
        arr(i + 2) = "b"
        arr(i + 4) = "c"
    Next i
    
    st = Timer
    For Each v In arr
        If v <> "" Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrNew(1 To 5, 1 To n)
            For j = 1 To 5
                arrNew(j, n) = v
            Next j
        End If
    Next v
    et = Timer
    Debug.Print "Loop in: ", et - st
    Stop
End Sub

Sub set2DArrayOutLoop()
    Dim arr(1 To 1000000) As String
    Dim newArr() As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer, n As Long
    Dim st, et

    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr) - 3 Step 5
        arr(i) = "a"
        arr(i + 2) = "b"
        arr(i + 4) = "c"
    Next i
    
    st = Timer
    
    ReDim newArr(1 To 5, 1 To UBound(arr))
    
    Dim j As Long
    n = LBound(newArr)
    
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) <> "" Then
            For j = 1 To 5
                newArr(j, n) = arr(i)
            Next j
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    ReDim Preserve newArr(1 To 5, LBound(newArr) To n - 1)
    
    et = Timer
    Debug.Print "Scott's Loop out: ", et - st
    Stop
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess that shows what it means when people say that `Redim Preserve` is an 'expensive' operation. If you add a counter, let's say `Dim z As Long`, and after each occurrence of `Redim Preserve...` add the line `z = z + 1` and change to `...et - st, z` then you will see that your solution does it 600.000 times, while Scott's only twice. That's the price you gotta pay. BTW, my machine needs 27 seconds for your solution, and less than half a second for Scott's.

Comment: @VBasic2008, Thanks for the answer.

Comment: There is no such thing as "Redim Preserve". On `Redim` a new, blank array is created. The `Preserve` addition causes elements from the previous version to be copied to the new, one by one, like in a *For / Next* loop. Therefore it's better to dimension the array too large initially and then cut it down to size once the requirement is known.

Comment: @Variatus, Thanks for the response.